# Asp.net with Entity Framework convert List to DataTable and then deliver to Excel template

Tags: asp.net, excel, entity-framework, templates, datatable

I have an ASP.NET MVC project, but I am new in this area, so I am struggle a lot to learn on the go.

I have to deliver the data from a database in a formatted excel.
I came to the conclusion that it is best for my project to use an Excel template
and then to populate it. I am using dynamic named range in Excel.

I tried to:

1. load related entities with Include() method,
2. then convert into a LIST
3. and convert the List into a DataTable and those into a DataSet
4. then use some function (that works well and is checked)
   to fill the Excel report with data from a DataSet (on specific cells
   with delimitators such as %name%)

It may not be the most effective method, but I got stuck at point 1) and I really need help...

Here is what I have so far:

Models

```
public partial class Activitydetail
    {
        public int ActivityDetailId { get; set; }
        public int ActivityId { get; set; }
        public string TimeType { get; set; }
        public double? Hours { get; set; }
        public int ComponentId { get; set; }
        public double? OkQty { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }

        public virtual Component Component { get; set; }   
    }

public partial class Component
    {
        public Component()
        {
            Activitydetails = new HashSet<Activitydetail>();
            Defects = new HashSet<Defect>();
            Modetails = new HashSet<Modetail>();
        }

        public int ComponentId { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ReferenceNo { get; set; }
       
        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Activitydetail> Activitydetails { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Defect> Defects { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Modetail> Modetails { get; set; }
    }

      public virtual DbSet<Activitydetail> Activitydetails { get; set; }
```

And Controllers:

```
public IActionResult Ex2(int id, int idc)
        {
            List<Activitydetail> data = null;
            try
            {
                data = DB.Activitydetails.Where(x => x.Activity.Moid == id && x.Activity.Mo.ClientId == idc)
                      .Include(x => x.Component)
                      .ToList();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
       
            var table11 = new DataTable();
            var table2  = new DataTable();
            table11 = ToDataTable2(data);
            table11.TableName = "table11";

           //return View(table11);

            var ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(table11);
            ds.Tables.Add("table2");

            ds.Tables["table2"].Columns.Add("col1");
            ds.Tables["table2"].Columns.Add("col2");
            
            FillReport("new2.xlsx", "template_mo1.xlsx", ds);
            string Files = "new2.xlsx";
            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Files);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Files, fileBytes);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
            return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "new2.xlsx");
        }


        public DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
            PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
            {
                dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
            }
            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                var values = new object[Props.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                }
                dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            return dataTable;
         }
```

Table11 is well created and all the values could be delivered into Excel file (into the name range table11, by cell name, for example %TimeType% or %Hours%).

The problem is that I want also to deliver the Component.Name or Componenet.ReferenceNo to Excel.

I tried with:

```
data = DB.Activitydetails.Where(x => x.Activity.Moid == id && x.Activity.Mo.ClientId == idc)
                      .Include(x => x.Component.Select(c=>c.ReferenceNo))
                      .ToList();
```

or with "IncludeThen", or by filling table2 with that values, but I get a lot of errors.

Comment: can you please share the error?

Comment: The error is: : error CS1061: 'Component' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no accessible extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'Component' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Include doesn't have any IEnumerable parameter, you can include entire Navigation property like `Include(x=> x.Component)`, and then check the data, data variable must have the properties like ReferenceNo

Comment: I did that with Include(x=> x.Component), then in my table11  I have all the values  for all the properties with the exceptions of Component.  Instead of a value I see this 
 "...Models.Data.Component"  How can I acces the ReferenceNo ?

Comment: can you share the screenshot of data in debugger

Comment: Still working on this but I think I found a better solution, not so complicated.  I take the LINQ query result and convert it into the Data Table.  Here is my help: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/convert-linq-query-result-to-datatable/

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a better solution, not so complicated, I take the LINQ query result and convert it into the Data Table.

I was inspired by this:
[https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/convert-linq-query-result-to-datatable/][1]
Here is my new code, after the data= .....ToList():

```
  var result = data.Select(x => new Activity_VM
               {
                   ActivityId = x.ActivityId,
                   Client = x.Activity.Mo.Client.Name,                     
                   MoNumber = x.Activity.Mo.Monumber,                              
                   Component = x.Component.Name,
                   Reference= x.Component.ReferenceNo     
               });
    DataTable table11 = LINQResultToDataTable(result);
```